# How to use my own custom js plugin within ionic 3 mobile app?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic2, ionic3

I created a js plugin using jQuery which I already used in my web application. Now I want use it on my **IONIC 3** mobile app.
I installed typings and jquery in my project those are working well there then how I can use my own custom jquery plugin in my IONIC 3 project.

Please give me a best possible solution.

Comment: If you have already imported jquery you can also just import your own custom js plugin and it should work. Ionic works just like any other web application.

Comment: how and where I import my plugin? in IONIC 3 it's not possible to include in index file like other web application as a src. so please give the way.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to include your plugin in the `index.html` file and that's exactly what you have to do.

Just copy your plugin to the `src/assets/` folder and then include it in your `index.html` like you would on any webapp:

`<script src="assets/plugin.js"></script>` (The path might be incorrect, you have to try which one works)

Comment: thanks for your answer. till now I'm little bit confused that there are not any index file in src/assets/. May I copy the index file from www/ folder?

Comment: No, everything inside the www/ folder can be overwritten during the build step. The index.html that you can edit should be inside src/

Comment: So, first time to edit the index file in src/  should be like the index file of www/ folder.